# How does MOXy handle empty arrays

Tags: jaxb, jersey, moxy

In my Jersey project, I am using MOXy to marshal to/from JSON. One of the classes I want to to marshal is an array of strings that could be empty.

```
class Data
{
   @XmlElement(nillable = true) public String[] array;
}
```

In the case where the array is empty, I would like the output to be:

```
{ 
   "array" : []
}
```

however it looks like MOXy is filtering out empty arrays from the output. How can I get it to include empty arrays in the output?

I was thinking about adding JSONConfiguration.mapped().array("array").build() to the MOXy provider constructor, but this doesn't seem to make a difference (and I'm not even sure that it's the correct solution).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The following enhancement request has been entered. You can use the link below to track our progress on this issue.

- http://bugs.eclipse.org/378894

---

**UPDATE**

Starting with the May 19, 2012 EclipseLink 2.4.0 label you can set the following property to get the behaviour you are looking for.

```
marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_MARSHAL_EMPTY_COLLECTIONS, true);
```

You can download nightly EclipseLink labels from the following location:

- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/downloads/nightly.php

**Root**

On the following class we have three `List` properties.  Two are of the `List` objects are empty and one is null.  Note that the `emptyChoiceList` field is mapped with `@XmlElements`.  The `@XmlElements` annotation states that the possible node names are `foo` and `bar`.

```
package forum10453441;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlType(propOrder={"nullList", "emptyList", "emptyChoiceList"})
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Root {

    private List<String> nullList = null;

    private List<String> emptyList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name="foo", type=String.class),
        @XmlElement(name="bar", type=String.class)
    })
    private List<String> emptyChoiceList = new ArrayList<String>();

}
```

**Demo**

The following code demonstrates how to specify the `MarshallerProperties.JSON_MARSHAL_EMPTY_COLLECTIONS` property.

```
package forum10453441;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.MarshallerProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        marshaller.setProperty(MarshallerProperties.JSON_MARSHAL_EMPTY_COLLECTIONS, true);

        Root root = new Root();
        marshaller.marshal(root, System.out);
    }

}
```

**Output**

Now in the output the empty lists are marshalled as empty arrays.  For the field that was mapped with `@XmlElememts` the node name that was specified was used in the JSON representation.

```
{
   "emptyList" : [ ],
   "foo" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks. We worked around this by using Gson to serialize this particular case. Glad to see that an enhancement came out of this. We may switch back to this when it's ready.

Comment: @Oleksi - We have added support the use case you described.  I have updated my answer with a full example.